# need a help with joining multiple tables from SQL in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Let's say I have 3 tables:

Table 1 called "states":

```
id | state
1    italy
2    netherlands
3    russia
```

Table 2 called "hotels":

```
id | hotel name | belongsToCountry
1    Green Hotel  2
2    Luxurious    2
3    Get Warm!    3
```

Table 3 called "free rooms":

```
id | roomID | belongsToHotel
1    815      2
2    912      2
3    145      1
4    512      1
5    1200     3
```

Now, what I need to echo is this:

> Netherlands has 4 free rooms.
>   Russia has 1 free room.

In words:
I need to make a list of **all states** which have **at least 1 free room** and I need to return the exact value of **how many free rooms there are**.

If anyone can help me with this, I'd be so grateful!

Comment: you want to remove [spaces] from your table names, field names: free_rooms, hotel_name

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's build the query step by step.

First, let's assemble the list of hotels and their free room count.

```
SELECT hotels.id, COUNT(*)
  FROM hotels
       INNER JOIN free_rooms ON(hotels.id = free_rooms.belongsToHotel)
 GROUP BY hotels.id
```

`INNER JOIN`s force rows from the table on the "left" side of the join (`hotels`) only to be included in the result set when there is a corresponding table on the "right" (`free_rooms`).  I'm assuming here that there will *only be a row in `free_rooms` when the room is free*.

Having this, we can now join against the list-o-nations.

```
SELECT hotels.id, COUNT(*), states.state
  FROM hotels
       INNER JOIN free_rooms ON(hotels.id = free_rooms.belongsToHotel)
       INNER JOIN states ON(hotels.belongsToCountry = states.id)
 GROUP BY hotels.id
```

It should be noted, by the way, that you've made poor choices in naming these columns.  `states` should be composed of `id` and `state_name`, `hotels` should be `id`, `hotel_name`, `state_id`, and `free_rooms` should be `id`, `room_name` and `hotel_id`.    (I could also argue that `states.id` should be `states.state_id`, `hotels.id` should be `hotels.hotel_id` and `free_rooms.id` should be `free_rooms.room_id` because that makes the joins much easier...)

If you need to represent a "belongs to" relationship, you're actually looking for [foreign key restraints](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_key).  You should use those instead of special naming.

*ahem* Where was I?  Oh yes.  The second query will result in a result set with three columns - the hotel id, the number of rooms in it, and the country it's in.  But, you just need the number of rooms per country, so let's do one last change.

```
SELECT COUNT(*), states.state
  FROM hotels
       INNER JOIN free_rooms ON(hotels.id = free_rooms.belongsToHotel)
       INNER JOIN states ON(hotels.belongsToCountry = states.id)
 GROUP BY states.state
```

Only two changes.  First, we're now grouping together by state.  Second, we're no longer including the hotel id in the result set.  This should get you the data you need, again assuming that there will never be a row in `free_rooms` when the room is not free.

Comment: Missing the HAVING clause (HAVING COUNT(*) > 0) but well written!

Comment: @judda, i don't think a having is needed here.  the free_rooms join takes out any "states" that don't have a free room already.

Comment: Shouldn't need one given the assumption that `free_rooms` only ever contains free rooms.  (Which is a horrible design idea, mind you.)

Comment: right it isn't ... not here.  Sorry about that was a quick glance :)

Comment: I have gotten to this only today and I must say your solution works perfectly and the explanation is very useful. Thanks a lot, sir!

Answer (score 1):

raw query - not tested:

```
SELECT state, COUNT( roomID ) AS rooms
FROM states
INNER JOIN hotels ON belongsToCountry = state.id
INNER JOIN free_rommms ON belongsToHotel = hotels.id

GROUP BY state
```

Comment: A HAVING clause should be added (HAVING COUNT(roomID) > 0).  And I think that these should be INNER JOINs rather than LEFT JOINs.

Comment: there are no need for it - no idicator that room is free - if it in free_rooms table -> is free - HAVING is useless

Comment: Except you are LEFT JOINing on the tables so the state would always be there no matter if free_rommms has it listed or not.

Comment: @judda - yes agree on LEFT -> INNER JOIN - fixed

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT state, COUNT(*) AS nb
FROM states AS S, hotels AS H, rooms AS R
WHERE S.id = H.belongsToCountry
AND H.id = R.belongsToHotel
GROUP BY state
HAVING nb >= 1
```

Comment: Why are you using a CROSS JOIN and then limiting it in your WHERE clause instead of using an INNER JOIN with the restrictions in the ON clause?

Comment: There is no harm here, the query planner is smart enough to do the right thing, even in MySQL.  It's sometimes easier to think of joins by gluing them together in the WHERE clause.

Comment: @judda, this is just an older style of ansi sql.  the query engine will generally optimize the two methods the same way, it's just generally agreed that having the join information in the join is more convenient for human readability.

Comment: @Charles, +1 for the underhanded jab at mysql. :)